# Insert column name and move the column data into the row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

[image: Original Dataset]

I want data like this
[image: Desire outcome]

When I use df.Column[] it replaces the value with name
[image]

Comment: While you are reading the csv file, there are arguments that allow you to set your column name, instead of taking the first row as header by default

Comment: Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question: Does the .xls file has column names? Or should you define them manually?

If it has column names (it seems like it doesn't), you can use header = 0 .If it doesn't have column names, define a list and then header = None and names =  column_names.

The first one is;

```
df = pd.read_excel('wine-1.xls', header = 0 ) # use read_excel instead of read_csv
```

and the second one:

```
column_names = ['wine', 'acidity',...] # list of column names

df = pd.read_excel('wine-1.xls', header = None, names = columns_names)
```

Hope that works for you.